# Panda3D-simplepbr running problem(FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory)

Tags: python, python-3.x, panda3d

I'm using macbook2019 monterey, Python 3.10.0, Panda3D 1.10.11

After I installed the `panda3d-simplepbr`, I try to run my program.
Here is my code:

```
import sys

import simplepbr
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase


class MyApp(ShowBase):
    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self)

        simplepbr.init()

        self.accept('escape', sys.exit)

        # base.disableMouse()

        self.jack = self.loader.loadModel("jack")
        self.jack.reparentTo(self.render)
        self.jack.setScale(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)
        self.jack.setPos(8, 50, 0)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gitdir/fyp/project/test_setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    base = AppBase()
  File "/Users/gitdir/fyp/project/test_setup.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.pipeline = simplepbr.init()
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplepbr/__init__.py", line 350, in init
    return Pipeline(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplepbr/__init__.py", line 128, in __init__
    self._recompile_pbr()
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplepbr/__init__.py", line 214, in _recompile_pbr
    pbr_vert_str = _load_shader_str('simplepbr.vert', pbr_defines)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplepbr/__init__.py", line 48, in _load_shader_str
    with open(os.path.join(shader_dir, shaderpath)) as shaderfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './shaders/simplepbr.vert'
```

If you know how to solve this problem please tell me.
Thank you for reading this post.